# How can I bitbang Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect for multiple AM2320 temperature sensors? Useage of bitbang libraries?

Tags: arduino, i2c

can you help me with the following?:
I'm a beginner and have an Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect and four AM2320 temperature sensors, but each have the same address, that can't be changed (this project is for my graduation exam). I got an info, that it is possible to create more I2C buses "in a software way" by using 4 functions (a start, a stop, one that can transmit a bit, and one that can read a bit). In this way, any of the digital pins can be programmed as SDA/SCL.
I have been told that there's a library named 'SoftwareWire', but I can't really understand the commands of it, and which comes after the other. Has anyone anything about this?

Searched for bitbanging in a 'software-way', found that there are libraries for this, but can't deal with the commands.

Comment: You should probably post your question at [arduino.se].

Comment: Maybe just use an i2c bus multiplexer IC? e.g. https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75016529.pdf -- "Designed for systems that use multiple I2C/SMBus devices with identical addresses..."

Answer (score 0):

hi i will pass to you a function that works for me with 3 i2c sensors sh21 with same adress

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "SHT2x.h"

uint32_t start;
uint32_t stop;

SHT2x sht;

float tempN1;
float humN1;
float dwn1;

float tempN2;
float humN2;
float dwn2;

float tempN3;
float humN3;
float dwn3;

int flip = 0;

void sht21read(){
    if (flip == 0)
  {

    Wire.begin(21, 22); // 2
    delay(100);
    // myHTU21D.begin();
    sht.begin(21, 22);
    start = micros();
    sht.read();
    stop = micros();
    delay(250);
    tempN1 = sht.getTemperature();
    humN1 = sht.getHumidity();
    // dwn1 = SHT2x.GetDewPoint();
    delay(250);
    Wire.end();
    flip = 1;
  }
  else if (flip == 1)
  {

    Wire.begin(32, 22); // 4
    delay(100);
    // myHTU21D.be sht.begin();gin();
    sht.begin(32, 22);
    start = micros();
    sht.read();
    stop = micros();
    delay(250);
    tempN2 = sht.getTemperature();
    humN2 = sht.getHumidity();
    // dwn2 = SHT2x.GetDewPoint();
    delay(250);
    Wire.end();
    flip = 2;
  }
  else if (flip == 2)
  {

    Wire.begin(27, 22); // 13
    delay(100);
    // myHTU21D.begin();
    sht.begin(27, 22);
    start = micros();
    sht.read();
    stop = micros();
    delay(250);
    tempN3 = sht.getTemperature();
    humN3 = sht.getHumidity();
    // dwn3 = SHT2x.GetDewPoint();
    delay(250);
    Wire.end();
    flip = 3;
  }
  else if (flip == 3)
  {
    flip = 0;
    Serial.print("TEMPERATURA N1= ");
    Serial.print(tempN1);
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.print("HUMEDAD N1= ");
    Serial.print(humN1);
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.print("||||");

    Serial.print("TEMPERATURA N2= ");
    Serial.print(tempN2);
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.print("HUMEDAD N2= ");
    Serial.print(humN2);
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.print("||||");

    Serial.print("TEMPERATURA N3= ");
    Serial.print(tempN3);
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.print("HUMEDAD N3= ");
    Serial.print(humN3);
    Serial.println("");

    delay(5000);
  }
}
```

then you run the function sht21read(); (or with your own name) on void loop and uala all working